# PHP Object 'user' goes away after refresh despite session continuing

Tags: php

New at PHP, following various OOP tutorials, ran into something I don't know how to fix.
Home.php

```
    <?php
        //echo '<img src="'.'uploads/photo.jpg'.'"alt="aaaaaa" style="width:256px;height:128px">';
        include_once "classes.php";
        $_SESSION['UserProfilePicture']=$user->getUserProfilePicture();//Dodging errors
        echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION['UserProfilePicture'].'"id="HOMEPROFILE" alt="No Profile Found" style="width:128px;height:128px"><br>';
    ?>
```

UserLogin.php

```
<?php
    include_once "classes.php";
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start(); //This is necessary above every file that uses session variables!
    }
    if(isset($_POST['UserMailLogin']) && isset($_POST['UserPasswordLogin'])){//Grab by name
        $user = new user(); //Adds an object
        $user->setUserMail($_POST['UserMailLogin']);
        $user->setUserPassword(sha1($_POST['UserPasswordLogin']));
        if($user->validlogin()==true){
            $_SESSION['UserName']=$user->getUserName();//Use -> when left is object, :: otherwise, => to assign key-value pairs in assoc array
            $_SESSION['UserMail']=$user->getUserMail();
            $_SESSION['UserId']=$user->getUserId();
            $_SESSION['Age']=$user->getUserAge();
            $_SESSION['UserLocation']=$user->getUserLocation();
            $_SESSION['UserProfilePicture']=$user->getUserProfilePicture();
        }
    }
?>
```

I have created a simple login system that starts the session. When a new $user object is made in the class called users, I have set/get functions that supply the object with its proper values. Meanwhile, the $_SESSION superglobal variables are also set. It takes them to the Homepage. On Home.php, I want to access $user->getUserProfilePicture(), which works, but upon refresh it can't seem to find the object $user. I've tried getting around this with using $_SESSION instead but that only delays the problem in the event that later I want to display other person's profile pictures and if I log out and log back in and refresh then it still has the same problem. Please help me find a way to keep the object $user. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Sorry guys I tried to cutout the nonessential stuff but I do have if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start(); at the start of every page

Comment: shouldn't you use session_start() even in home.php ?

Comment: Right sorry I have it this was just a snippet of the file because the real thing is quite long but I have if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start;   Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe for this to work you will need to recreate $user on every page. Once you browse away from the login page it was created on, the object will be destroyed.

If you store user ids in the database, try having a way to create a user object from just the user id, so you won't need to keep the password in a session to recreate it.

The other option is to store the required user values in the session and only use them rather than relying on the $user object.

Also make sure you are calling session_start() on every page using sessions.

Comment: YAAAAAAAY Thanks a bunch dude been stuck on this for a few hours been thinking of switching languages but then I started calling from the query and works like a charm. Later I'll have to find out how to apply this to other users (when they're user ID's aren't a part of the session but that should be simpler). I don't know if there's some caveats to asking the database too often (will it slow down?) but for right now cheers I forgot about traversing the database

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend learning procedural programming as you get started because initially OOP does not make sense. Why do you need the overhead to run a small script? You don't!

Also use `require_once();` instead of any includes to avoid any and all headaches associated.

For session the ideal is to store limited data into the session in a centralized place so you don't have to think about it.

Something along the lines of a require_once session file that checks if a user has a session and if so does stuff. Then you can depend upon having the data readily available in all places.

To answer your question, this line prevents your session from populating unless there's been a submit:

```
   if(isset($_POST['UserMailLogin']) && isset($_POST['UserPasswordLogin'])){//Grab by name
```

Working prototype for what you appear to want:
If you can limit session data to the barebones and use each script to load the user data based on id otherwise you'll pay a price for the hefty session overhead.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // do all your require_once here.

    $aPost = $_POST;
    $aPost[ 'username' ] = 'coolcat';
    $aPost[ 'password' ] = 'dontchangeme';

    if( !empty( $aPost[ 'username' ] ) && ( !empty( $aPost[ 'password' ] ) ) )
    {
        // Authenticate user object here and see if they can be 'logged in'
        // Stubbing out section.
        $oUser = new stdClass;
        $oUser->username = 'coolcat';
        $oUser->email = 'cool@cat.com';
        $oUser->id = 99;
        $oUser->age = 13;
        $oUser->location = 'NYC';
        $oUser->photo = 'coolcat.jpg';
        $_SESSION[ 'userid' ] = $oUser->id;
    }

    // If we have a 'logged in' user show them stuff.
    if( !empty( $_SESSION[ 'userid' ] ) )
    {
        echo 'You\'re logged in!';
    }
    var_dump( $_SESSION );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I did make $aPost, a permanent alternative to $_POST and changed the if statement. Unfortunately it still didn't show. I'm sure you had the right method, and maybe I was doing something wrong. Also, thanks so much for the advice and require_once, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Run session_start(); without an isset check.

Comment: What does that do? It doesn't seem to change anything right now. Thanks